# React native build assembleDebug works fine but assembleRelease Crash from specifics screen

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm new to react Native,
React native build assembleDebug  works fine but assembleRelease Crash from specifics screen
this is my output log when i try to build in assembleRelease build, How should I fix it
my build gradle is 7.2.2
and react-native version is  0.70.6

```
Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-vector-icons:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Execution optimizations are disabled to ensure correctness. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
                Welcome to Metro v0.72.3
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated


info Writing bundle output to:, /home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Writing sourcemap output to:, /home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/intermediates/sourcemaps/react/release/index.android.bundle.packager.map
info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 16 asset files
info Done copying assets
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:1726:23: warning: the variable "DebuggerInternal" was not declared in function "__shouldPauseOnThrow"
        return typeof DebuggerInternal !== 'undefined' && DebuggerInternal.shouldPauseOnThrow === true;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:4926:7: warning: the variable "setTimeout" was not declared in function "logCapturedError"
      setTimeout(function () {
      ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:3524:21: warning: the variable "clearTimeout" was not declared in anonymous function " 95#"
    cancelTimeout = clearTimeout;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:7424:30: warning: the variable "__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__" was not declared in anonymous function " 95#"
  if ("undefined" !== typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:7439:146: warning: the variable "nativeFabricUIManager" was not declared in anonymous function " 124#"
    null != handle._nativeTag && (null != handle._internalInstanceHandle ? (handle = handle._internalInstanceHandle.stateNode, null != handle && nativeFabricUIManager.dispatchCommand(handle.node, command, args)) : _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[2]).UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(handle._nativeTag, command, args));
                                                                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:8209:5: warning: the variable "setImmediate" was not declared in function "handleResolved"
    setImmediate(function () {
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
 
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:11319:24: warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "readBlobAsArrayBuffer"
      var reader = new FileReader();
                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:11356:36: warning: the variable "Blob" was not declared in anonymous function " 307#"
        } else if (support.blob && Blob.prototype.isPrototypeOf(body)) {
                             
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:26058:32: warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "onUpdate"
        this._animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.onUpdate.bind(this));
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:49694:76: warning: the variable "Buffer" was not declared in function "convertValue"
        return useBlob && typeof Blob === 'function' ? new Blob([value]) : Buffer.from(value);
                                                                           ^~~~~~
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle:50679:56: warning: the variable "btoa" was not declared in function "dispatchXhrRequest"
        requestHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password));
                                                       ^~~~

> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:compressReleaseAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/mergeReleaseAssets'. Reason: Task ':app:compressReleaseAssets' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/ahmed/Downloads/Qam-third/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/mergeReleaseAssets'. Reason: Task ':app:compressReleaseAssets' uses this output of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Execution optimizations are disabled to ensure correctness. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 2 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using certain libraries which don’t support [Hermes Engine](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes).

To fix it in React Native (v0.70.6) follow these steps:

1. Open `android/app/build.gradle` file and search for `enableHermes`
2. Disable the Hermes engine

   ```
   project.ext.react = [
       enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
   ]
   ```
3. Clean the gradlew

   ```
   cd android && ./gradlew clean
   ```
4. Build release

   ```
   ./gradlew assembleRelease
   ```